# Tel link hover styles always showing

Tags: html, css, tel

For starters, I have different phone link styles than regular link styles. I am trying to use border-bottom as the link underline (to meet AA accessibility requirements) and would like for the color to change upon hover/focus. I currently have it set to have an alpha of .2 as a default state and switch to an alpha of 1 on hover. This same effect is working fine on regular links, but when I apply it to `a[href^="tel:"]` the hover state is applied all the time (for the border-bottom only).

I have tested this with rgba values (ideal solution) as well as two different HEX codes and I have the same issues.

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: $text-body;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

a[href^="tel:"]:hover,
a[href^="tel:"]:focus,
a[href^="tel:"]:active {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: In `border-bottom`, the default colour is `currentcolor`. Solution: put the colour in the `border-bottom` property or put `border-color` after it.

Comment: Do you want to get something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/5mpr3uLw/

Comment: @MrLister That fixed it, the linter wanted them ordered the other way for some reason but swapping them fixed the issue, thank you!

Comment: @Banzay yes that is the functionality I'm looking for. Thank you!